# stop python in terminal on mac

Tags: python, macos, terminal

Using python in terminal on a Mac, type

```
ctrl-z
```

will stop the python, but not exit it, giving output like this:

```
>>> 
[34]+  Stopped                 python
```

As you can see, I have stopped 34 python calls.

Although I could use

```
>>> exit()
```

to exit python, the questions are:

1. Is there a short-key to really exit (not just stop) python in terminal? and, why

   ctrl-c

   does NOT work?
2. How do I kill all the stopped python?

BTW, how could I type 'ctrl-c' and other hotkeys with a keyboard look?

Thanks!

Comment: To kill all other running instances of python, type the following command in your terminal:

killall -vs SIGKILL python

Answer (score 32):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> ->  Defines EOF (End of File).

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> ->  Will terminate most jobs.

If, however you have written a python wrapper program that calls other python programs in turn, Ctrl-c will only stop the the job that is currently running.  The wrapper program will keep running.  Worst case scenario, you can do this:

Open up:  Applications -> Utilities -> Activity Monitor,  Find the process labeled as python, highlight it in the activity monitor then click on "Quit Process".

These three suggestions should work for most situations where you want a program to stop.

Comment: More directly:  yes.  Ctrl-d will stop the python terminal.  Also if you have any other questions regarding python and it's terminal, type: "help()", in the terminal.  Exploring this little program will teach you many things.  :)

Comment: CTRL + d Quit the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Python issue, per se.  This ia a Unix shell behavior and is a difference from Windows and other systems.  See the [Wikipedia article on CTRL-Z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z) for a more complete explanation:

> On Unix-like systems, Control+Z is the most common default keyboard
>   mapping for the key sequence that suspends a process (SIGTSTP).
>   When entered by a user at their computer terminal, the currently
>   running foreground process is sent a SIGTSTP signal, which generally
>   causes the process to suspend its execution. The user can later
>   continue the process execution by typing the command 'fg' (short for
>   foreground) or by typing 'bg' (short for background) and furthermore
>   typing the command 'disown' to separate the background process from
>   the terminal.

On OS X as on various other Unix-based systems, you could use the `stty` command to change which key, if any, produces a `SIGTSTP` (or an `eof`, for that matter):

```
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; 30 rows; 90 columns;
lflags: icanon isig iexten echo echoe echok echoke -echonl echoctl
    -echoprt -altwerase -noflsh -tostop -flusho pendin -nokerninfo
    -extproc
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel iutf8
    -ignbrk brkint -inpck -ignpar -parmrk
oflags: opost onlcr -oxtabs -onocr -onlret
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -dsrflow
    -dtrflow -mdmbuf
cchars: discard = ^O; dsusp = ^Y; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
    eol2 = <undef>; erase = ^?; intr = ^C; kill = ^U; lnext = ^V;
    min = 1; quit = ^\; reprint = ^R; start = ^Q; status = ^T;
    stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; time = 0; werase = ^W;
$ stty susp ^Y
$ cat
^Y
[1]+  Stopped                 cat
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> while clicking <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> as well...

Answer (score -1):

You can type CTRL + D to quit python.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).